# Force the browser to take user to the TOP of the page when the back button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser

When the back button is clicked the user is taken to not only the previous page but also the part of the page where he/she was before coming to the present page. At least this is the behavior in Firefox.

So for example, if you are at the bottom of a page and you click on one of the footer links and then you click the back button, you will be taken to the footer part of the previous page.

Is there a way to force the browser to disregard what part of the page the user was and just take them to the top of the previous page every time when the back button is clicked?

Comment: Attempting to change default browser almost always begins with a bad user experience design.

Comment: You could achieve this the way @dystroy shows you. However is there a serious reason to override the browser's behavior ? Your users are used to their browser behavior, which assumes that "when you click on the back button, you would like to go to the previous position in the page"

Comment: @Bathz yea normally I wouldn' but I have a page that has tabs and ajax loaded listings in those tabs. The 1st tab only has a few items, the others have many more. When the use clicks on one of those other tabs and goes to another page and then clicks back button they are taken further down on the previous page whose default tab has only 1 or 2 items and that far down the page is empty.

Comment: In this case I would suggest to change the URL part of page when tab is clicked. You can also use HTML5 navigation API to change full URL, not just the hash part. On page load, you could see which tab to select by hash. Backbone.js (http://backbonejs.org) has nice lib for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this :

```
   <script>
    $(window).load(function(){$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'fast');});
   </script>
```

But I agree with Steve and Bathz : check your web page needs it as users don't like the browser comportment to be changed.

Comment: I've tested this solution but doesn't work in Google Chrome, any suggestion to let it work in Chorme too?

Answer (score 0):

It might work with less than 100 milliseconds, I like the effect!

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }, 100);
});
```